# python - how to convert a nested list to a list of all individual sub-lists

Tags: python, list, nested-lists, python-3.4

I have a Nested List like this:

```
l = [['A', ['A', 'B', ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'D']], ['A', 'D', ['A', 'D', 'A']], ['A', 'C', ['A', 'C', 'B'], ['A', 'C', 'A']], ['A', 'A', ['A', 'A', 'D']]]]
```

I want to separate it to a List of all individual lists like this:

```
k = [['A'], ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'D'], ['A', 'D'], ['A', 'D', 'A'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'C', 'B'], ['A', 'C', 'A'], ['A', 'A'], ['A', 'A', 'D']]
```

I tried this by creating the following function:

```
def un_nest(l):
    k=[]
    for item in l:
        if type(item) is list:
            un_nest(item)
        else:
            k+=[item]
    print(k)
```

I got the required output, but I don't know how to convert it to list.
the output I got is:

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
['A', 'B', 'D']
['A', 'B']
['A', 'D', 'A']
['A', 'D']
['A', 'C', 'B']
['A', 'C', 'A']
['A', 'C']
['A', 'A', 'D']
['A', 'A']
['A']
[]
```

this was output in the shell, (I know this is because of print function), but i have no idea how to get the list from this. As I need to do some operation the the required list for final output.
I am using Python 3.4.1
Any hint will help. Thanks in advance

Edit:
Its more like I want to, separate all the strings and sub-list from 'l', to another list.

Comment: So what you want is: [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'D'], etc.]

Comment: Yes, exactly. The output which was printed from the function, I want it as a list.

Comment: there is no list `['A']` in your input.

Comment: ['A'] is the first character from the first list ['A', ['A', 'B', ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'D']]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: What if the input is `['A', ['A', 'B'], 'C']`, do you want `[['A'], ['A', 'B'], ['C']]` or `[['A', 'C'], ['A', 'B']]`?

Comment: @PeterWood No, this is not a duplicate because a completely flat list is not desired.

Comment: @JanneKarila, you are right flat list is not desired. and expected output for ['A', ['A', 'B'], 'C'] is [['A', 'C'], ['A', 'B']]. And it seems rpattiso's answer solves it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could return a list as the result at the current nesting level and join together the nested results using extend.

```
l = [['A', ['A', 'B', ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'D']], ['A', 'D', ['A', 'D', 'A']], ['A', 'C', ['A', 'C', 'B'], ['A', 'C', 'A']], ['A', 'A', ['A', 'A', 'D']]]]

def un_nest(l):
    r = []
    k = []
    for item in l:
        if type(item) is list:
            r.extend(un_nest(item))
        else:
            k.append(item)
    if k:
        r.insert(0, k)
    return r

print(un_nest(l))
```

outputs:

```
[['A'], ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'D'], ['A', 'D'], ['A', 'D', 'A'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'C', 'B'], ['A', 'C', 'A'], ['A', 'A'], ['A', 'A', 'D']]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that's exactly what I wanted.